# JSON Serialising "on" instead of "true"

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, serialization

When i type this into the chrome console

```
$('#myForm').serialize()
```

I get the serialised response

```
Flag1=on&Flag2=on
```

When this goes off to MVC, it doesnt match Flag1 or Flag2 to `True`. So defaults them to `False`.

Why are they being serialised as `on` rather than `true`, or how to i get MVC to accept it?

My html if it helps is generated as

```
 <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="Flag1" name="Flag1" checked />
```

Comment: Set `value="true"` as attribute. `If the value attribute was omitted, the default value for the checkbox is on` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/checkbox

Comment: @A.Wolff I have done this as you said and it (obvious to you) works great! I am right in thinking it should contain `value="true"` regardless of whether checked or not, and this just tells it what checked means?

Comment: If you use MVC and you use `@Html.CheckBoxFor` then it will create a checkbox with `value=true` for you *along with* an hidden input with the same name but with `value=false` - that way, if you checkbox is *not* ticked, you still get a boundable value.

Answer (score 1):

Please try doing like this

```html
 <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="Flag1" name="Flag1" checked value="True" />
```

and in your controller

public ActionResult Index(bool Flag1 = false)

Keep the default value because if checkbox is checked,only then the postback values will contain a key value pair of the form